# Insert the timestamp column in the scandate column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery, bigdata, tableau-api

I want to insert the timestamp column in the values of ScanDate column with Null values.

I need to use this in tableau and if I keep the values separetade, I got wrong results

```
select distinct A.RootDocId, A.LastEventAppId, A.LastEventStatus, 
        case when B.Value = '' then A.Timestamp else 
        PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', 
replace(regexp_replace(B.Value, '[/-]1([7-9]) ', '/201\\1 '), '-', '/'))
        end ScanDate, C.Value Federation, A.timestamp 
from `serv.dam.documentroot` A 
left join unnest(Metadata) B ON B.Key like 'ScanDate' 
left join unnest(Metadata) C ON C.Key like '%ederation'
        limit 100
```

I expected this :

[image]

Where Scandate is `null`, it should be replaced with the `timestamp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select RoodDocId,
       LastEventAppId,
       LastEventStatus,
       coalesce(ScanDate, timestamp),
       Federation,
       timestamp
from (
    -- here your whole query that you have
) a
```

Answer (score 2):

> Where Scandate is null, to be replaced with the timestamp

You should use [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions) function

as `COALESCE(Scandate, timestamp)`

Or you can just "fix" your query (`B.Value = ''` --> `IFNULL(B.Value, '') = ''`) as below

```
select distinct A.RootDocId, A.LastEventAppId, A.LastEventStatus, 
        case when IFNULL(B.Value, '') = '' then A.Timestamp else 
        PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', 
replace(regexp_replace(B.Value, '[/-]1([7-9]) ', '/201\\1 '), '-', '/'))
        end ScanDate, C.Value Federation, A.timestamp 
from `serv.dam.documentroot` A 
left join unnest(Metadata) B ON B.Key like 'ScanDate' 
left join unnest(Metadata) C ON C.Key like '%ederation'
        limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Its usually better when using Tableau to model your relationships (joins) in your Tableau data source, and let the tool generate optimized SQL for your specific visualization. If you hand write your own SQL, Tableau will respect it of course, but not try to optimize it.

Almost anything you would do in mainstream SQL is available in Tableau without resorting to hand written SQL if you decide to explore that route. The Tableau calculation equivalent for SQL's Coalesce() is called IF_NULL().

Comment: i am forced to rewrite sql/bigquery querys and to not use Tableau tools. This querys are for bigquery in cloud and i had to reshape a view so i can gather the datas. Thank you for the advice :)